# Need help to configure network in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: network-manager, 17.04

My host system is running **Ubuntu 17.04**, on which I have installed **VMware Workstation v12.5.7**. I have a virtual machine running **CentOS 7** and want to configure a static IP address.

Do I need a static IP configured on my host? If yes, how do I do this?

if no then also, how?

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

No, the host system does not require an static IP address to install virtual machines that access the network.

When you create your virtual machine, you must define the [type of connection](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-3B504F2F-7A0B-415F-AE01-62363A95D052.html) it will use:

- **bridged networking**, where the VM has direct access to the network. Here the VM must acquire a different IP address (e.g. from a DHCP server) and may require bringing the network interfaces up/down (e.g. by using `ip link` 
  or `ifconfig`) in the VM each time you change of network.
- **NAT**, where the VM connects to the network (and internet) through the host system. Using this type of connection, the VM is not accessible from the outside.
- **host-only**, where the VM connects only to the host system.

I think you must use a NAT connection. using this connection, your VM will have network/internet access while the host system has access. If you need to access servers/services in the VM you may configure a port forwarding for NAT.

If you need to configure TCP/UDP port forwarding, [please look here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html).